# Aplicar cor na fonte em elemento clicado apenas com CSS

Tags: css

Eu tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo">Fale Conosco</div>
```

Quando eu clicar na div `trabalheSubEsqTitulo`, quero que ele aplique `color:red`, porém, quero isso somente com CSS.

Tem como fazer?

Comment: Nunca testei, mas tente o seguinte: `.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:active{ color: red; }`

Comment: Precisa ser div ou pode ser outro elemento?

Comment: @Felipe queres que se mantenha após o click certo?

Comment: @JorgeB. exato, manter a cor após o clique.

Comment: @FelipeStoker ou usa a solução do **bfavaretto** ou utilize JS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Com div não sei se é possível, mas com uma âncora você pode usar a [pseudo-classe `:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), assim:

```css
.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:visited { color: blue; }
.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:target { color: red; }
```

```html
<a id="nome-unico" href="#nome-unico" class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo">teste 1</a>
<a id="outro-nome-unico" href="#outro-nome-unico" class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo">teste 2</a>
```

O identificador no `href` precisa ser único, e coincidir com o `id` de cada item. A regra do `:visited` é para manter o azul nos links já clicados. Cuidado que essa regra precisa vir antes da outra no CSS.

O `:target` funciona assim: se a URL atual do documento possui um *hash* (`#qualquer-coisa`) igual ao ID de um elemento, esse elemento é o `:target`. No nosso exemplo, ao clicar em cada link definimos o hash do documento como o ID desse mesmo link. Ele então passa a ser selecionado pelo `:target` declarado no CSS.

Comment: Eu acrescentaria só um `.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:visited { color: blue; }` no CSS para manter a cor original quando não estivesse selecionado.

Comment: Incorporei sua sugestão :)

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer isso usando o pseudo-seletor [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), porém o efeito só fica enquanto estiver a carregar/pressionar o rato. Para manter a classe acho mesmo que só com JavaScript.

```css
.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:active {
    color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo">Fale Conosco</div>
```

**Existe uma outra maneira** que é usar uma checkbox como uma flag... Juntando um label com o atributo `for="check"` (que aponta para a ID da checkbox) e escondendo a checkbox, podemos fazer assim:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check" class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo">Fale Conosco</label>
```

Comment: Acho que não é isso que ele quer...

Comment: @JorgeB pois... então acho que só mesmo com JS.

Comment: Exato, gostaria que ele mante-se a cor após o clique, só com CSS não tem como então?

Comment: @FelipeStoker juntei mais uma solução :)

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra forma seria utilizando o atributo `tabindex`, exemplo:

```css
.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:focus {
  color: red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo" tabindex="0">Fale Conosco</div>
```

O lado ruim desta solução é que ele trabalha com o estado de *focus*, ou seja se você mudar o foco para qualquer outro elemento, o seu perderá a cor vermelha.

Para uma solução a prova de balas e 100% eficiente, ainda é necessário o uso de JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Desconheço manter a cor apenas com CSS após clicar, porém, para manter a cor após o clique deveria ser um link e o seletor seria `:visited`

Para setar a cor quando clica ficaria assim:

```
.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:active {
    color:red;
}
```

Demontração Fiddle:

```css
.trabalheSubEsqTitulo:active {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="trabalheSubEsqTitulo">Fale Conosco</div>
```