# Como manipular tamanho de div sem utilizar hover

Tags: php, css, css-hover

> **Edited** -- *Apesar de ter pedido exclusivamente em css, vi que de fato o resultado final em JS é muito mais profissional e enxuto. Sendo
>   assim confirmei a resposta de @renan como a que auxiliou de fato.
>   Contudo ressalto aqui que a resposta de @Fetz foi realmente a melhor
>   saída para a utilização de CSS nesse caso. Entretanto o efeito final é
>   feio, movendo a página inteira de lugar.*

Minha dúvida é simples. Tenho usado muito o `:hover` no CSS e tem me servido até certo ponto.

Contudo tenho desejado uma coisa diferente. Queria poder clicar numa `div` para que ela aumentasse de tamanho, e que eu tivesse que clicar nela num canto específico para ela diminuir.

O `hover` faz parte do processo, mas quando tiro o mouse de cima da `div` ele volta ao tamanho anterior.

O que quero é que a `div` só mude quando eu clicar nela. E se possível ela só volte à forma original se eu clicar num `X` por exemplo ou fora da `div` em questão.

Já procurei muito, encontrei algumas coisas em JS, mas estou fazendo o possível para não utilizar JS nesse meu projeto. Então comecei a imaginar que com PHP isso seja possível. Ou alguma palavra chave de CSS pra colocar no `stylesheet` no lugar do `hover`.

Tem alguma palavra reservada para isso como por exemplo um possível `onmouseclick` da vida???

Grato antecipadamente.

```
#atredit{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#atredit:hover{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: Hanzer, mesmo parecendo irrelevante neste caso, considere que incluir um trecho de código (apenas o trecho que quando vc tira o mouse de cima da div ele volta à forma original) vai aumentar muito uas chances de receber  respostas.

Comment: obrigado @gustavox

Comment: Editei meu comentário anterior pra constar o trecho que acho importante vc incluir.

Comment: Tem como, usando javascript.

Comment: O PHP não consegue mudar tamanhos de div pois ele não tem como modificar as configurações dela. Mas Jquery consegue perfeitamente solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Me tira uma dúvida @SamuelNeiva O Jquery tem relação com o JS? Seria mais interessante usar Jquery ou JS?

Comment: O Jquery é feito em javascript, só que mais polido. Melhor usar o jquery pois ele possui classes prontas para fazer o que você quer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode inserir uma classe responsável por aumentar o tamanho do *div* quando este for clicado, por exemplo, uma classe que expande o tamanho do *div* em 'x' *pixels*.

A forma como você vai fazer isso depende do suporte que você quer dar aos usuários (na verdade, ao navegador que eles utilizam). Existe a API [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) mas o Internet Explorer ainda possui implementação parcial, como [pode ver neste *link*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). No entanto encontrei [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript) no StackOverflow<sup>en</sup> na qual existem formas de contornar esse "problema" no IE.

Um exemplo utilizando a API `classList`:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('ativa');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red
}
div.ativa {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('ativa');
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red
}
#foo.ativa {
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div id='foo'></div>
```

Comment: vlw @renan! 

no caso isso é JS? De todo modo agradecido!

Comment: olá novamente @renan! Sendo JS como procedo para ao invés de usar div como no exemplo seu eu usar a id da div?

Comment: compreendo que provavelmente seja '#varid

Comment: `document.getElementById("id-div").addEventListener(...);` @HanzerDjAlgonn

Comment: Eu coloquei como a resposta escolhida por mim, mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar. Por esse motivo retirei agora. 

Eu n sei o que fazer. Entrou com JS eu fico perdido por que ainda não me aprofundei o suficiente e por isso eu insisti na pergunta pra obter uma opção fora JS. Eu coloquei o trecho do código document.getElem... na minha página html entre as tags script. Eu n sei se precisa de mais alguma coisa pra fazer funcionar, pois n tenho conhecimento suficiente em JS. Se puder dar mais uma força ficarei grato

Comment: @HanzerDjAlgonn colocou onde? No caso, o código teria que ser inserido depois do elemento HTML. Se você tentar chamar essa função antes (no head, por exemplo) não irá funcionar. Vale lembrar que não entra só a questão do Javascript mas do CSS também, editei minha resposta e criei um novo *snippet* pegando o div pelo id.

Comment: testei de várias formas. Funcionou agora. Eu salvei o código numa página fora do html .js. Coloquei a chamada do código acima da tag </body>. Funcionou lindamente! Grato profundamente. Apesar de não ser somente css agradeço deveras o esforço! vlw

Answer (score 3):

Com css apenas podes fazer assim:

Se usares o pseudo selector `target` em vez do `hover`.

Para usares o target, precisas de ter um id (ex:`<div id="show">`) no elemento que vai crescer e um link a apontar para o id do elemento que queres que cresca (ex: `show`) com o prefixo # (ex:`<a href="#show">`)

html:

```
<a href="#">x</a>
<div id="show">
    <a href="#show">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/201" alt="Kitten 2"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
#show img {
    height: 150px;
}

#show:target img {
    height: 300px;
}
```

exemplo a funcionar:
http://jsfiddle.net/zzsLb6g9/

Comment: [Concordo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40789/74).

Comment: uou!! Isso chegou muito perto! 

Realmente aumentou e agradeço deveras! Contudo a página se moveu pra cima. Tem alguma âncora que eu possa colocar para resolver isso? Toda vez que a página for chamada essa âncora segurar em determinado ponto?

Comment: Essa reação de movimentar a página me desagrada deveras. 
por isso, apesar de sua resposta ser a que mais se aproximou do que pedi aceitei a do brother acima por que o efeito final foi realmente melhor em JS. Contudo muito grato por me mostrar essa possibilidade.